# Cannot read property 'getDataRange' of null

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I`m very new working with google script and APIs and I`m trying to run a piece of code that makes the sheet in to a Json however I`m facing an issue where it says:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDataRange' of null
json    @ Code.gs:4
```

The code I`m using is the following:

```
 function json() {
      const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("APItest")
      const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
      const jsonData = convertToJson(data)
      return ContentService
            .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(jsonData))
            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
    }
```

I already tried to change the getSheetID but also didn`t work

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're getting null value after the execution of

```
const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("APItest")
```

And That's why you get the error in the next statement. make sure that the sheet is not null.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Problem is that the sheet is not null. I wrote some fake data like Name and Age with 5 rows, 6 if you count the Name an Age

Comment: well there may not be a function for the sheet like getDataRange() or if it's, It returns null would you please check those separately in the console screen?

Comment: @MarianaRodrigues It means no sheet with the given name exists. Check the name of the sheet not the contents of it.